# PGP keys missing

Tags: pgp

today I opened my GPA and none of my keys are showing up, I didn't make any kind of expiration date, and I'm almost 90% sure I didn't delete them by hand. Where could they have gone? Is it possible for me to find them somewhere in my files? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. This question is off-topic here because it is asking about the function of a particular program. I would migrate to a more appropriate site, but you do not provide enough detail to help. You only state that something is missing and you cannot find it. That's not a lot to work with to come up with an answer.